# Rounding Program

Tags: c++, rounding

I need to round some input numbers using `C++`. Below is my code. `

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  cin >> a;
  for (int i =0; i<a; i++) {
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;
    int result = b/c;
    if (result > 0) {
      cout << floor(result + 0.5) << " ";
    } else {
      cout << ceil(result - 0.5) << " ";
    }
  }
}
```

However, I constantly get answers that are too low.

Example input:

```
15
6525 1410
14431 510
9163 480
5461 1938
6969 1220
-7065150 -4171886
-9268414 -1461265
17913 584
-32381 -634679
19887 1666
5133363 4488942
5440267 601
4700414 923
4699610 15
4322342 201
```

Output: `4 28 19 2 5 1 6 30 -0 11 1 9052 5092 313307 21504`

Expected: `5 28 19 3 6 2 6 31 0 12 1 9052 5093 313307 21504`

What did I do wrong? (And why did I get negative zero on one of those?)

Comment: Please do not edit a question to change it significantly. It invalidates the answers that you have received so far. Instead, ask a new question in these cases. I don't understand what you mean by "I could not add a problem".

Comment: the website prevented me from asking a new question.

Comment: I don't know why you can't ask other questions, but in any case overwriting one turning it into a new one isn't allowed. And it isn't even effective, because many people don't even read it, seeing that there are already 2 answers. So please click on edit and roll it back to revision 2. As for asking a new question, maybe you have been suspended for some reason (in which case you should have been clearly informed). Just wait until the suspension expires, or contact the site staff if you think it's a technical problem.

Comment: Great, thank you. One final thing: Since E. Maskovsky's answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted, by clicking on the tick on its left. You will also gain some reputation by doing it.

Comment: thanks Favio, for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the division in int, not in float. You can do this to fix:

```
double result = static_cast<double>(b)/c;
```

and better to use floor also for value of 0 to avoid the negative zero, i.e.

```
if (result >= 0.0) {
```

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, what does "static_cast<double>" do?

Comment: The static_cast casts from int to double, so that the division is done in floating point then and does not cut off the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem, in addition to doing the division as an integer division, as the other answer pointed out, is that you should use [std::round(3)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/round.3.html). Manually adding/subtracting .5 is susceptible to round-off errors, and there is no reason to reinvent the wheel when `std::round` will do the job for you.